# Displaying Only part of website in webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to display only a specific part of some websites in my Android WebView.
I went through almost all the available solution online, but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

I used Jsoup, and HTML Cleaner, it displayed correctly but CSS and JavaScript of the page were lost.

Tried to use JavaScript in onPageFinished through WebViewClient, still nothing.

For example, If I display [https://gaana.com](https://gaana.com/song/dekhte-dekhte-8) then I want to display [only this part of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L8Sw.png) which is in  .

I have below code in onPageFinshed which is not working, please let me know if I am missing any minor thing here. ` wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
"document.getElementById('Gaana-Home-Top_Ads').style.display='none'; " +

"document.getElementByClassName('breadcrum').style.display='none'; " +

"document.getElementByClassName('activeonscroll').style.display='none'; " +
"document.getElementByClassName('lastend-container').style.display='none'; " 
+

"document.getElementByClassName('mobile_search').style.display='none'; " +
"document.getElementByClassName('mobile-playlist-option').style.display='none'; " +

"document.getElementByClassName('bodyloader').style.display='none'; " +
"document.getElementById('mp').style.display='none'; " +
"document.getElementByClassName('Gaana_ROS_ATF_728adunit').
 style.display='none'; " 
 +

"document.getElementById('ads_645x60_pd_high').style.display='none'; " +
"document.getElementById('language-form').style.display='none'; " +


                    "})()");

        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(URL);` .
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try the @media rule? (resize screen to view example)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @media Rule</h1>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "yellow".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

with this rule, you can get it when the application is running on a smartphone, maybe it will be for you, if the accesses with webview will always come from mobile phones.

See more on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thanks for the ans, but I do not own the website, so can not change its code. I have multiple websites which I want to be trimmed as per webview.